# getting null pointer exception because can't create bean

Tags: java, spring, wildfly

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
 xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
 default-autowire="byName"
 xmlns:oxm="http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm"
 xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm/spring-oxm-4.3.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.3.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.3.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.3.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.3.xsd">
 <bean id="userRoleDAOTarget"
  class="com.revguru.crs.security.dao.UserRoleDAOImpl"
  scope="prototype">
  <property name="sessionFactory" ref="hsdSessionFactory" />
 </bean>
 <bean id="userAuthDAOTarget" class="com.revguru.crs.security.dao.AuthenticationDAOImpl" scope="prototype">
  <property name="sessionFactory" ref="hsdSessionFactory" />
 </bean>
 <bean id="hotelUserDAOTarget" class="com.revguru.crs.security.dao.HotelUserDAOImpl" scope="prototype">
  <property name="sessionFactory" ref="hsdSessionFactory" />
 </bean>
 <bean id="userRoleDataObjprocessor" class="com.revguru.crs.security.service.UserRoleProcessor" scope="prototype">
  <property name="userRoleDAO" ref="hsdSecurityObjectDAO" />
 </bean>
 <bean id="userAuthDataObjprocessor" class="com.revguru.crs.security.service.AuthenticationProcessor" scope="prototype">
  <property name="authenticationDAO" ref="hsdSecurityAuthObjectDAO" />
  <property name="messages" ref="userSectionMessageSource"/> 
 </bean>
 <bean id="hotelUserDataObjProcessor" class="com.revguru.crs.security.service.HotelUserProcessor" scope="prototype">
  <property name="hotelUserDAO" ref="hsdHotelUserDAO" />
  <property name="securitySectionLogger" ref="generalServiceLogger"/>
 </bean>
 <bean id="SECURITY_SERVICE" class="com.revguru.crs.core.service.sc.SecurityService" scope="prototype">
  <property name="userRoleProcessor" ref="userRoleDataObjprocessor" />
  <property name="userAuthProcessor" ref="userAuthDataObjprocessor" />
  <property name="hotelUserProcessor" ref="hotelUserDataObjProcessor" />
 </bean>
 <bean id="hsdSecurityObjectDAO" class="org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactoryBean">
  <property name="proxyInterfaces">
   <value>com.revguru.crs.security.dao.UserRoleDAO
   </value>
  </property>
  <property name="interceptorNames">
   <list>
    <value>hibernateInterceptor</value>
    <value>userRoleDAOTarget</value>
   </list>
  </property>
 </bean>

 <bean id="hsdSecurityAuthObjectDAO" class="org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactoryBean">
  <property name="proxyInterfaces">
   <value>com.revguru.crs.security.dao.AuthenticationDAO
   </value>
  </property>
  <property name="interceptorNames">
   <list>
    <value>hibernateInterceptor</value>
    <value>userAuthDAOTarget</value>
   </list>
  </property>
 </bean>
 
 <bean id="hsdHotelUserDAO" class="org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactoryBean">
  <property name="proxyInterfaces">
   <value>com.revguru.crs.security.dao.HotelUserDAO
   </value>
  </property>
  <property name="interceptorNames">
   <list>
    <value>hibernateInterceptor</value>
    <value>hotelUserDAOTarget</value>
   </list>
  </property>
 </bean>
 <bean id="userSectionMessageSource"
  class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource" scope="prototype">
  <property name="alwaysUseMessageFormat" value="true"/>
  <property name="basenames">
   <list>
    <value>userauthResources/hsd_user_msg</value>    
   </list>
  </property>
 </bean> 
</beans>
```

this is my bean file and it is getting reference to hsdsessionFsctory wich is defined as below:

```html
<bean id="dataSource" destroy-method="close" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
  <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
  <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/revguru"/>
  <property name="username" value="root" />
  <property name="password" value="decoder" />
 </bean>
 
 <bean id="hsdSessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
  <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
  <property name="hibernateProperties">
```

and when i run my project i get null pointer exception

```html
public class UserLoginController {
 
 private FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
 HttpSession session = (HttpSession)FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSession(true);
 private SecurityService securityService;
 
 public void setSecurityService(SecurityService securityService) {
  this.securityService = securityService;
 }
 
 public SecurityService getSecurityService() {
  return this.securityService;
 }
 
 /**
  * Authenticate the User
  * @return 
  */
 public String authenticate() {
  if(session.getAttribute("menus") != null) {
   session.removeAttribute("menus");
  }
  
  if (session.getAttribute("CommonGlobalBean") != null) {
   session.removeAttribute("CommonGlobalBean");
  }
  
  CommonGlobalBean commonGlobalBean = new CommonGlobalBean();
  commonGlobalBean.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault().getID());

  UserLogin userLogin =(UserLogin)session.getAttribute("UserLogin");
  
  String username = userLogin.getUserName();
  String password = userLogin.getPassword();
  
  UserInformation userInformation = null; 
  System.out.println("security serv ice  is ");
  if(securityService==null){
   System.out.println("security serv ice  is null:");
   securityService= new SecurityService();
  }
  if (userLogin != null) {
   System.out.println("username is:"+username);
   System.out.println("password is:"+password);
   
   if (securityService.authenticate(username,password)) {
    Util.log("Get User Object by Email");
    UserDataObject userDataObject = securityService.getUserObjectByEmail(userLogin.getUserName());
    Util.log("User name : "+userDataObject.getUserFirstName());
    userInformation = (UserInformation)session.getAttribute("UserObject");
    if (userInformation != null) {
     session.removeAttribute("UserObject");
    }
    userInformation = getUserInformation(userDataObject);
    session.setAttribute("UserObject", userInformation);
      
    if(!checkUserAsHotelRole(userInformation)) {
     Util.log("User does not have hotel role.");
     Util.reportError(facesContext, "login_user_not_valid_password", null);
    }

    HotelDataObject hotelDataObject = getAssignedHotel(userInformation);
    session.setAttribute("hotelDataObjectInSession", hotelDataObject);
    
    List<Menu> menus = new ArrayList<Menu>();
    for (FeatureDataObject feature : userInformation.getFeatureDataObjects()) {
     if (feature.getParentFeatureId() == null && feature.getFeatureTypeId().getId().intValue() == HSDServiceConstants.MENU && feature.getShowFeature() == 1) {
      List<MenuItem> menuItems = getMenuItems(feature.getId(), userInformation.getFeatureDataObjects());
      menus.add(new Menu(feature.getId(), feature.getFeatureName(), "", menuItems));
     }
    }
 
    String languageCode = userLogin.getLanguageCode();  
      
    if (languageCode == null) {
     userLogin.setLanguageCode("en");
     facesContext.getViewRoot().setLocale(Locale.ENGLISH);
    } else {
     if(languageCode.equals("fr")) {
      facesContext.getViewRoot().setLocale(Locale.FRENCH);
     } else {
      facesContext.getViewRoot().setLocale(Locale.ENGLISH);
     }
    }
    
    Util.log(":: languageCode :: " + userLogin.getLanguageCode());
    
    session.setAttribute("menus", menus);
    session.setAttribute("CommonGlobalBean", commonGlobalBean);
    /**
     * get hotel general info details
     */
    GeneralHotelController generalHotelController = new GeneralHotelController();
    generalHotelController.loadGeneralInformation();
    /**
     * return to hotel general info page
     */
    return "generalInfo";
   } else {
    Util.log("Invalid User.");
    Util.reportError(facesContext, "login_user_not_valid_password", null);
   }
  } 
  return "";
 }
```

which call another method to class as follow

```html
public boolean authenticate(String email, String password) {  
  log.info("Authenticating : " + email);
  UserDataObject user = getUserObjectByEmail(email);
  if (user == null) {
   log.info("User does not exist for email id :" + email);
   return false;
  }
  return checkPassword(password, user.getPassword());
 }
```

when i see it in my spring explorer it shows me Bean ref is unknown

this is my stack trace

```html
javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NullPointerException
javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:659)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:129)
org.apache.myfaces.webapp.filter.ExtensionsFilter.doFilter(ExtensionsFilter.java:357)
io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:292)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:138)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:135)
io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:272)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:104)
io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:202)
io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:805)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

whats is red mark in my spring explorer

[image]

while others don't have it

Comment: can you show your error code?

Comment: means which error code

Comment: i am getting nullpointer exception at this line                                                    if (securityService.authenticate(username,password))

Comment: can you paste your console error?

Comment: did you try to add `depends-on="hsdSessionFactory"` clause on your beans who depend on hsdSessionFactory?

Answer (score 0):

`UserLoginController` is not configured as a bean in your XML (at least not in the XML you've posted), therefore Spring knows nothing about it and you get no injections.

Try adding this (with full package of course):

```
<bean id="loginController" class="com.revguru.crs.security.dao.AuthenticationDAOImpl" scope="prototype">
        <property name="securityService" ref="SECURITY_SERVICE" />
</bean>
```